# PHP Warning Permission denied (13) on session_start()

Tags: php, session, warnings

I'm getting the following error:

```
PHP Warning:  session_start() [<a href='function.session-start'>function.session-start</a>]: open(/tmp/sess_49a20cbe1ef09a2d0262b3f7eb842e7b, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) in /home/------/public_html/includes/libs/ss.inc.php on line 1
```

The problem doesn't happen all the time, but comes and goes.

This the code at line on 1 in ss.inc.php

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
```

Comment: Looks like you don't have write rights for the /tmp directory at your site. Are you sharing the system with others?

Comment: If I'd have a guess, I'd say the `/tmp` dir is sometimes full. You can alter the path where sessions are stored with [`session.save_path`](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-path)

Comment: looks like you don't have permissions to read the file, what did ls -al say?

Comment: What kind of a server are you using? It looks like your www user doesn't have permission to write `/tmp` which could be set up on purpose by your host if you have one. You might need to send your web host an email to get this resolved unless you can `chmod` yourself

Comment: @nobody well i'm not sharing system with any one.. 
and permission of temp folder is 755 thanks

Comment: For symfony2 session access folder have a look at: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/session/sessions_directory.html

Comment: I solved it by just deleting the files as this "sess_e8vjrvit9duq61r9inj1iof285" from the /temp folder, so it creates a new session which has permission. This may have happened because you uninstalled and installed apache or something, at least with me that's how I solved it.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You don't appear to have write permission to the `/tmp` directory on your server. This is a bit weird, but you can work around it. *Before* the call to `session_start()` put in a call to `session_save_path()` and give it the name of a directory writable by the server. [Details are here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-save-path.php).

Comment: Or PHP's session.save_path is not configured to /tmp. It may require changing session.save_path, e.g. `session_save_path("/tmp");`.

Comment: ini_set('session.save_path',getcwd(). '/'); session_start();

Comment: My problem was similar, but it was the "session" path that had incorrect permission.  (/var/lib/php/session on CentOS 6.6)  I simply ran "sudo chown root:nginx session" and the error went away.

Answer (score 17):

Do a `phpinfo()`, and look for `session.save_path`. The directory there needs to have the correct permissions for the user and/or group that your webserver runs as.

Answer (score 6):

I have had this issue before, you need more than the standard `755` or `644` permission to store the `$_SESSION` information. You need to be able to write to that file as that is how it remembers.

Answer (score 4):

PHP does not have permission to write on `/tmp` directory. You need to use `chmod` command to open `/tmp` permissions.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you don't have WRITE permission on `/tmp`.

Edit the configuration variable [`session.save_path`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-path) with the function [`session_save_path()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-save-path.php) to **1 directory above** `public_html` (so external users wouldn't access the info).