# session_start() not working on mac

Tags: php, macos, session

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I fix the Permission error when I call session_start()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4585086/how-can-i-fix-the-permission-error-when-i-call-session-start)
>   [PHP Warning Permission denied (13)  on session_start()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6821532/php-warning-permission-denied-13-on-session-start)

I am trying to make an admin panel. Unfortunately session does not work on macbook.
I have everything installed and working, also latest php at this time.

I just cannot manage to get it working on my mac. It does work on my paid hosting however I cannot work on that.

Please help me to resolve this issue. I believe it's something about permission writing or so.

[image: Preview of ACP]

Comment: As you can read in the comments, the directory, your server is trying to save the session, has no `write permission`. Either set the permissions for that folder, or use a different folder, that has the wright permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the permissions on:

```
/var/folders
```

I would suggest changing the ownership of the folder:

```
sudo chown -R nobody /var/lib/php/session
sudo chgrp -R nobody /var/lib/php/session
```

The 'nobody' option being the user that your webserver runs under and for the second command it's the group.

Note: The folder would need to be changed to wherever you have set your session.save_path to. In the question above the folder is `/var/folders` so the code would be `chown -R nobody /var/folders`

Comment: I tried to type two of these commands in iTerm but I dont get nothing...
My user is dvLden so I type chown -R dvLden /var/lib/php/session and I get chown: /var/lib/php/session: No such file or directory

Comment: You would need to set the folder as your folder name. So the error message says the folder is: /var/folders. So you would type the command as above but change the folder name

Comment: Okay if I set my folder name like you said I get following error:
Operation not permitted and Permission Denied. With all folder names that are within.

Comment: You may have to use the `SUDO` command to do it then

Comment: Okay with SUDO first command worked. Second one does not work either with or without SUDO :(
chgrp: dvLden: illegal group name

Comment: there's no group by the name you've specified (as you've selected your username probably). You can list your groups with `dscl . list /groups` - you then need to choose the group which is most appropriate (probably your webserver group - i.e NGINX if your using that)

Comment: I dont have NGINX... I dont know what is that.
However what will happen' if I type owner ? 

Also I Have tried only to set permission to read&write on everyone and only that way it worked...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20173/discussion-between-nenad-dvl-and-socialrel8)

Comment: Yes  - i'm in the chat room.

Answer (score 2):

Duplicate of [PHP Warning Permission denied (13) on session_start()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6821532/php-warning-permission-denied-13-on-session-start)

It's basically the write permissions, you can also right-click on the folder and grant access to everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Set more permission to your session folder:

```
/var/folders/
```

perhaps its better when you set the [session save path](http://php.net/manual/de/function.session-save-path.php) to a temp directory.

Comment: I will read about session save path in that case.

Comment: I have ended into redirect loop :D

Comment: ^^ then there is anything wrong but i think you find the solution. At top is a link to another post. And you should find a solution.