# Wordpress PHP Permissions Denied Error

Tags: php, wordpress, permission-denied

I am receiving the following errors all of my websites pages.

Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: open(/tmp/sess_110024a16996bb35c7f6d138127e6f13, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) in /home/summeybo/public_html/wp-content/themes/freely/admin/options.php on line 2

Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/summeybo/public_html/wp-content/themes/freely/admin/options.php:2) in /home/summeybo/public_html/wp-content/themes/freely/admin/options.php on line 2

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/summeybo/public_html/wp-content/themes/freely/admin/options.php:2) in /home/summeybo/public_html/wp-login.php on line 368

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/summeybo/public_html/wp-content/themes/freely/admin/options.php:2) in /home/summeybo/public_html/wp-login.php on line 380

I have even attempted a fresh install with the theme that we purchased and have had no luck. I have also attempted to change the permissions of the tmp folder.

Comment: Are you installing this via the scripts or through a website panel via a shared host?

Comment: I installed wordpress via ftp and the theme via the wordpress panel.

Comment: Have you tried it without the theme that you purchased? Try using one of the built in themes.

Comment: I have it is not until the theme is installed that I get these errors. This is for a client so I am trying to fix the theme.

Comment: seems like theme is doing a redirection after some output has been done, or check if every php file is surrounded by <?php tags.

Comment: see this [link][1], maybe it help you 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6821532/php-warning-permission-denied-13-on-session-start

Comment: which plugins do you have installed?

Comment: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/transferring-site-to-new-server-using-whm this guy had this problem too because of tumblrize

Comment: Ok, I fixed it. Thanks to Skatox and Igor. The gentleman who developed the theme left out the ending ?> at the end of the options.php document in the admins folder for the theme. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem thanks too Ok, I fixed it. Thanks to Skatox and Igor. The gentleman who developed the theme left out the ending ?> at the end of the options.php document in the admins folder for the theme. Thank you guys!