# Intergrating Facebook SDK into Laravel

Tags: php, facebook, session, laravel

I've been following [this guide](http://maxoffsky.com/code-blog/integrating-facebook-login-into-laravel-application/) to integrate Facebook into my Laravel Project.

Everything was going smoothly until this:

```
Route::get('login/fb', function() {
    $facebook = new Facebook(Config::get('facebook'));
    $params = array(
        'redirect_uri' => url('/login/fb/callback'),
        'scope' => 'email',
    );
    return Redirect::to($facebook->getLoginUrl($params));
});
```

Which I got the following error:

> ErrorException session_start():
>   open(/var/lib/php/session/sess_09h29gh7n3ve9blh36o9jun4q2, O_RDWR)
>   failed: Permission denied (13)

I searched online and got [the following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4585086/how-can-i-fix-the-permission-error-when-i-call-session-start) result, which told me to change session path, or contact server administrator. I've also seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6821532/php-warning-permission-denied-13-on-session-start)

So the question is, how should I fix this? Can I just use any path with `session_save_path()`?

Comment: Does this happen consistently? If you clear all your cookies for the domain (it may be safer to clear all cookies in your browser if you want to be sure you've cleared the cookies) does it still happen? It could be a one-off that is just happening to your current session id, and nothing related to the Facebook SDK.

Comment: I've cleared my browser cookies and it still happens. Any ideas?

Comment: No sorry - the only time I've seen that error is when I go to a site that's hosted on a server using SuPHP and I accidentally happen to use a session ID that was given to a different site (and thus it tries to read the other process's session ID tmp file and get this permission error) - a simple `if (!@session-start()) { @session_regenerate_id(); }` seemed to work for me in that case, but obviously this was pre-Laravel when I used plain old PHP :)

Comment: What does `session_save_path()` do though? I'm afraid to try because I'm don't know what it does exactly. Don't want it to screw up server settings :S

Comment: It [changes where your sessions are stored](http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/function.session-save-path.php) (for the current request). As far as I can tell you can use this just fine, as long as you set it to a directory that will always be available and can be ready from and written to by whatever user the current PHP process is.

Comment: @alexrussell yeah I've tried that yesterday and it seems to work. I have no idea whether it changes anything on my server though.

Answer (score 0):

`session_save_path()` seems to solve it. I created another folder with 777 settings and this issue seems to go away. I am unsure however, whether it affects anything on the PHP server.