# Warning: session_start(): failed: Permission denied (13)

Tags: php, session

I am getting the error:

```
Warning: Unknown: open(/tmp/sess_beaac196b5082a77131f957bcfa35ee7, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) in Unknown on line 0

Warning: Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/tmp) in Unknown on line 0
```

I have checked the /tmp directory and it is writable (using this code):

```
$filename = '/tmp';
if (is_writable($filename)) {
    echo 'The file is writable';
} else {
    echo 'The file is not writable';
}
```

The php.ini file says session.save_path is /tmp

Is there something obvious I'm missing?

EDIT: I have tried setting a new session path but even after CHMOD 777 it gives me a tells me:

```
Warning: session_start(): open(/sessions/sess_beaac196b5082a77131f957bcfa35ee7, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2)
```

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6821532/php-warning-permission-denied-13-on-session-start).

Comment: I read through that previously and created a session folder with full write permissions and tried to use that. I still got the error :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I fix the Permission error when I call session\_start()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4585086/how-can-i-fix-the-permission-error-when-i-call-session-start)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `session_save_path()` on page starting

refer : http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-save-path.php

Answer (score 1):

I eventually managed to get it working by putting the full path of my new folder in..

`session_save_path('/home/scittwebhost/sessions');`

I still do not know why I couldn't write to `/tmp` - the permissions were 777

Thanks all