# open(/var/lib/php/session/...sesionid, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13)

Tags: php, nginx, session, amazon-ec2

I am running my website on using ec2 nginx.
I have done a update on the instance and now I getting this error when the site loads.

```
open(/var/lib/php/session/sessionid, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) in /var/www/html/includes/session.php on line 17

 session_start(): Failed to read session data: files (path: /var/lib/php/session) in /var/www/html/includes/session.php on line 17
```

I am wondering how to fix this?

Appreciate any help
Thanks

Comment: `/var/lib/php/sessions` is probably owned by `root:root` - try setting the [session save path](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-save-path.php) to a directory that's writable by the PHP user.

Comment: That's the way to go... see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6821532/php-warning-permission-denied-13-on-session-start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You install PHP from zero in this machine? You already tried to put a complete permission in this folder?
Ex: `sudo chmod 777 -R /var/lib/php/session`

Comment: This fixed it thank you. Everything was working fine then I installed composer. After that it broke so not sure why.

Comment: Setting `777` is actually a rather bad idea, you don't want to open any part of the system more than what's minimally required. Consider this SO thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27039635/warning-session-start-failed-permission-denied-13 which will eventually lead to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6821532/php-warning-permission-denied-13-on-session-start

Answer (score 0):

You need to set correct ownership for the `/var/lib/php/session` folder. In case your webserver is running from nginx user that might be `chown -R nginx:nginx /var/lib/php/session` or if you are using apache that's `chown -R www-data:www-data /var/lib/php/session` where nginx and www-data is the user and user group from which webserver is running.