# Error on session_start

Tags: php

I get the following error within my code:

> Notice: session_start(): ps_files_cleanup_dir: opendir(/var/lib/php5)
>   failed: Permission denied (13) in
>   /var/www/worldofthegods/data/www/worldofthegods.com/public/armory/engine/classes/sessions.none.php
>   on line 22

and it's talking about this:

```
protected function _start()
{
  global $config;

    session_name($config['AuthCookieName'].'_hash');

    session_start();

    return true;
}
```

Maybe u guys can help me out since I can't find the error.

Kind Regards,
Mikey Romkes

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6821532/php-warning-permission-denied-13-on-session-start check these answers

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

In your `php.ini` set `session.gc_probability` to 0

It is caused due to automatic session garbage collection. Disable it and you are on.

In Debian and Ubuntu, `/var/lib/php5`, where the session data is stored, has permissions of `drwx-wx-wt` and should only be cleaned by a cron script. So, the package maintainers disable automatic session garbage collection.

But, other php5 packages (like php5-cli) don't have garbage collection disabled.

Comment: Working around the problem does not fix the problem.

Comment: Restart apache server